# Knockout options binding, options are not displayed

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm struggling with the options binding for knockout.js.
When I don't use the options binding, like this

```
<select id="AddProductSelect" name="chosenSpaProduct">
   <!-- ko foreach: Spa.SpaProductList -->
         <option data-bind="text: Name" ></option>
   <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

it works fine. On the row below I'm trying to use the options binding like this

```
<select data-bind="options: Spa.SpaProductList, optionsText: 'Name'"></select>
```

nothing shows up in the select-element.

Spa.SpaProductList is a array of objects. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Edit:
Relevant JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       var initialData = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
       viewModel = new ViewModel(initialData);
       ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
       viewModel.ViewLoaded(true);

       function ViewModel(initialData) {
           var self = this;
           ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData, {}, self); 
           (...)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant javascript? Model, model initialization and applyBindings() code.

Comment: Because based on the code you have supplied, this should be working as demonstrated in this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vYdVS/  Which leaves me with thinking it has to do with your reference of `Spa.`

Comment: @FeistyMango added the js you asked for. I think you are right about the reference of spa, but don't really know how to debug. Any tips and tricks? I have tried with the $root.Spa... to make sure Im in the root of the ViewModel but it didn't help.

Comment: I know you didn't include your entire view model, but you didn't even include how "Spa" or "SpaProductList" are defined in your view model.  Your HTML/binding is fine.  Here's an example using your exact HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/b55FF/ There must be something wrong in your view model.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `optionsValue` parameter. From the [knockout.js documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

> If you want to let the user choose from an array of arbitrary JavaScript objects (not merely strings), then see the optionsText **and optionsValue** parameters

Here's the example they give:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsText: 'countryName', value: selectedCountry"></select>
```

Comment: The value attribute is used to track what value the user picked and is not needed to display the list. The jsfiddle in the comment by Feisty (under the question) shows that it works without it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the optionsText.

This example is working: (http://jsfiddle.net/geremora/6VmCh/)

HTML:

```
       <select data-bind="options: cars,
                   optionsText: 'brand',
                   value: selectedCar,
                   optionsCaption: 'Select...'"></select>
```

JS:

```
var Car = function (brand, model) {
   this.brand = brand;
   this.model = model;
};

var viewModel = {
   cars: ko.observableArray([
    new Car("Audi", "A3"),
    new Car("Ford", "Ranger"),
    new Car("Fiat", "500")]),
   selectedCar: ko.observable(), 
 };

 viewModel.selectedCar.subscribe(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
 });

 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: It's true. Sorry, there should be a small error. Can you put the code in jsFiddle or plunker?.